# how to index data from database using solr

Tags: java, solr

I configured Import Handler for fatching data from MySql data base. In the solr example which i downloaded from net in C:\apache-solr-1.4.0\example\example-DIH\solr\db\lib there is hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar. 
I want to know:

> since i am using MySQL do i need to
>   put jar for MySql.

Answer (score 2):

please be sure to check out the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) as it very much describes the process of indexing data from a MySQL database.

As for you question regarding where to put the MySQL connector jar (in my case it is called the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar")... you will need to place this jar in the C:\apache-solr-3.1.0\example\lib\ folder.

Hope that helps!